# Irregular shaped gradient fill in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, fill

I want to make a gradient fill for a shape in illustrator but I don't know how to make it follow this shape. Any tips on how to do this? Thank you.

[image: Text effect I need to make.]

Comment: If you're talking about the gloss, you can draw and embed it into the text using 'clipping mask'. Other than that, it has two different strokes,  and a radial gradient as the fill in it. Go to the Appearance Panel and play with it.

Comment: It's a *minimum* of 3 objects... the purple/magenta and then the white gradient areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a mask, controling gradients with that many colors or with such a complex shape would be almost imposible to fill.

Comment: Hey Diana, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!